# Test Lab execution status does not pass back to Test Plan exec status for few scripts

Tags: quality-center

The Execution status of scripts is different in Test lab and test plan ,seems the execution status is not getting updated for some scripts in test plan . the scripts  are passed in test lab but in test plan ,the execution status shows no run or not completed

let me know the solution to overcome this issue ...

i am using QC 11

Comment: What do you mean by *"scripts"*?  Are you referring to Tests that have been automated?

Answer (score 3):

In QC/ALM
Test Plan and Test Lab are completely different.

Tests are generated in test plan.  Scripts are not executed from this location.  This is where they are stored.

Tests are run out of Test Lab.  You map the test lab suites to pull the tests from test plan.  The execution status is tracked in the lab.  You can't change that status in plan.  You could easily use the same script in 10 different instances in lab so you wouldn't want it to update plan.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Actually, although you are correct in most aspects...the Execution Status of the last Run from the Test Lab is automatically assigned to the Execution Status in the Test Plan.  This is also used when determining the status of requirements.  So I'm not sure your answer is completely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about the Test Status, there are two distinct status assigned to a Test.

1. **TS_STATUS**: The test's current status. The values are from the Plan Status custom list.  Typical values are: Ready, Besign, Imported, Repair.
2. **TC_EXEC_STATUS**: The execution status of the test.  The values are from the Status custom lsit.  Typical values are: Not Completed, No Run, Passed, N/A, Failed

The first one can be seen within the Client easily in the details of a Test.  The execution status was behind the scenes until the advent of Test Configurations.  It can be seen in the Test Configurations tab of the Test Plan if you have a recent enough version of HP ALM. So that brings the question, which status are you talking about?

If you are talking about the Test status then there is no relation to the Test Lab as this just represents the readiness of the Test itself.

I'll assume therefore that you are talking about the execution status.  You say that

> The Execution status of scripts is different in Test lab and test plan

One scenario that this could happen is if you run the Test multiple times.  Let's say you run it twice and it has a status of Failed first, then run it a second time and it Passed.  You could be looking at the first execution which has a status of Failed, but the Test itself will show Passed.  This is because the Test inherits the last execution status.

You also said

> the scripts are passed in test lab but in test plan ,the execution
>   status shows no run or not completed

If it is No Run, then I don't have all of the information I need.  The only case where it would be No Run is if it was never run (or possibly if it was run and then the Execution Status in the Test Lab was changed back to No Run).  However, if you are seeing Not Completed this could be because you have multiple Test Configurations and you have run some and not others.  When looking at requirements tied to a Test that has multiple configurations, you will see a rolled up status of Not Completed in this case.  This may also be elsewhere in the system and specifically in the `TC_EXEC_STATUS`.  Each Test Configuration actually gets its own status in its own database table [ `TEST_CONFIGS.TSC_EXEC_STATUS`].  This is what you are seeing in the Client.

Without more information on what field you are talking about and under what conditions this is happening I cannot give a more definite or detailed answer.  I hope this helps you solve your issue.